# Sort lots of large compressed files

Tags: bash, sorting, compression

I have a lot of large compressed files called xaa.gz, xab.gz, xac.gz etc.  Unfortunately they are not sorted.  I would like to do the equivalent of the following.

```
zcat x*|sort > largefile

split -l 1000000 largefile
```

Then gzip the split files and throw away all the other files made before as well.

The problem is this makes a massive uncompressed file  and then lots of smaller uncompressed split files before then compressing them. Is it possible to do the whole thing without making a huge file in the middle of the process and ideally without saving the split files before compressing them either?

I have 8 cores so I would like to take advantage of them too (I don't have coreutils 8.20 so can't take advantage of sort --parallel).

Comment: Do you want to sort the individual files or combine everything, sort, split?

Comment: Combine, sort, split.  That's what I can't quite see how to do efficiently.

Comment: Why are you interested in keeping the file split into chunks? Do you not trust the filesystem or is there some unstated reason? Do you know that `sort` CPU will be the dominant cost in this, or are you prematurely optimizing because you can?

Comment: @msw They will be large so I want to process them independently eventually so that the processing stage can fit into memory.

Comment: Then I would suggest that you are in fact making optimization decisions in advance of measurable performance problems. The Linux file system is extraordinarily good at ensuring that needed data and anticipated needs are already in memory when you try to get them. If you try to guess what your performance bottlenecks will be, you'll frequently be wrong and in this case, your "cure" might actually be less efficient than the disease you anticipate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the full code, but some ideas on what you can do here.

1) partition input files to process them in parallel:

```
num_cores=8
i=0
while read f; do
  part_name=part$i
  set $part_name="${!part_name} $f"
  (( i=(i+1)%num_cores ))
done < <(ls x*.gz)
```

2) decompress and sort some part of files in different processes:

```
sort -m <(zcat $part0 | sort) <(zcat $part1 | sort) ...
```

3) tell split to compress files immediately:

```
... | split -l 1000000 --filter='gzip > $FILE.gz'
```